# Order issue for results

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13OG7.png)

Hello,

As marked in the picture how can i get that record as a last?

Example : My data currently coming as **Del1 Del10 Del11 Del2 Del3 Del4 Del5 Del6 Del7 Del8 Del9** but it should be  **Del1 Del2 Del3 Del4 Del5 Del6 Del7 Del8 Del9 Del10 Del11** , Can any one help me to write this query properly.

```
select distinct ih_deliv  as DelRef
from ihead
where ih_deliv <> ' ' and state <> 2
order by 1
```

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.) ?  We need to know this in order to provide a specific query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From your image, I can see that the data has DEL followed by numerical part.
If that's the case - You can use the following SQL query to order the data.

```
select 
    distinct ih_deliv as DelRef 
    ,cast(substring(ih_deliv from 'DEL([0-9]+)') AS integer) as num
from 
    ihead
where 
    ih_deliv <> ' ' 
    and 
    state <>2 
ORDER BY 2
```

---

**Explanation:**

**cast(substring(ih_deliv from 'DEL([0-9]+)') AS integer):**

- "substring" extracts the numeric part following "DEL" from the
  ih_deliv column
- "cast" changes it to integer.

**order by 2 :** Orders the data by second column in the select in ascending order

---

> If you only want "ih_deliv" column in the output, you can use the
> above code in subquery.

```
select "DelRef" from
(
    select 
        distinct ih_deliv as DelRef 
        ,cast(substring(ih_deliv from 'DEL([0-9]+)') AS integer) as num
    from 
        ihead
    where 
        ih_deliv <> ' ' 
        and 
        state <>2 
    ORDER BY 2
) as sub_query
```